# Windows 8 Background Downloader Issue

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm having an issue with a Windows 8 metro application that I am building.  I am using the JavaScript Windows 8 library for this application.

My issue is that I have some code which downloads a file using the built in BackgroundDownloader.  When I test the code on my local machine it work beautifully.  The file downloads as expected and everything works.  But when I run remote debug mode and push the application to my Windows8 Pro Tablet the downloads don't even get triggered.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: First, check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the BackgroundDownloader. I just download some amall images und so I use a HttpClient and it works.

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                        filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
writer.WriteBytes(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
await writer.StoreAsync();
writer.DetachStream();
await fs.FlushAsync();
```